# How do I replace a comma separated list of strings with the first occurrence?

Tags: php, regex, pcre

```
WHERE MATCH (COALESCE(f1, f2, f3)) AGAINST (?) > 0
WHERE MATCH (COALESCE(f1)) AGAINST (?) > 0
```

Wanted:

```
WHERE MATCH (f1) AGAINST (?) > 0
WHERE MATCH (f1) AGAINST (?) > 0
```

Need to substritute `COALESCE(f1, f2, f2, ...)` with just `f1`, that is the first string if multiple string are present (separated by `,`) or just the string itself.

[I'm working on this](http://rubular.com/r/8ykEdGcKZv):

```
#\s*match\s*\((\s*coalesce\s*\((.+)\s*\))\s*\)\s+against#/i
```

And i'm capturing both what's inside `MATCH` (1, what's need to be replaced) and what's inside `COALESCE` (2, the replacement).

How do I substituite 1 with the first value inside 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace should start at `COALESCE` but the previous part must match. Use [\K for resetting](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K) after (where replacing should start). So the first part could look like `MATCH\s*\(\K` here starts replacing and pattern continues: `\s*COALESCE\s*\(\s*([^,)]+)`... capturing in first capture group.

And the optional part `(?:,[^)]*)?` to meet a closing bracket. For the `AGAINST` part a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) can be used: `(?=\)\s*AGAINST)`. So the whole pattern could be:

```
/MATCH\s*\(\K\s*COALESCE\s*\(\s*([^,)]+)(?:,[^)]*)?\)(?=\)\s*AGAINST)/i
```

And replace with captured `$1`. [Test at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/mD6vA4/4)

Comment: I was really far from getting this to work. Thank you a lot, works amazing even with multiple `MATCH`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the following to match:

```
(MATCH\s*\()COALESCE\(([^,)\s]+)(?:\s*,[^)]+)?\)
```

And replace with `$1$2`

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mD6vA4/6)

Comment: If you mean without `MATCH` then no. Out of curiosity, `COALESCE` is automatically added to my SQL and it's wanted most of the time. Unfortunately you can't use `MATCH(COALESCE(f1, f2))` so I need to remove it.

Comment: @gremo you want to remove `MATCH` also? I dint get your point.. please check the demo.. :)

Comment: I see, you always substitute `COALESCE`. But I need to do it only in inside `MATCH`, as explained in my fist comment, that is `SELECT COALESCE(a, b)` should remain as is.